# Creating a Leaflet Map in Shiny Using Multiple Years From Different Columns

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, shinyapps

I am trying to create a map where users can select to view trail count data from a list of trailheads by year. I have figured out to do a single year, though not elegantly, and am now trying to include multiple years. Here a simple dataset that is representative of the dataset I am using.

```
     site <- c("Browns Canyon", "Hancock", "Monarch Crest")
     lat <- c("38.76210", "38.70581", "38.49185")
     long <- c("-105.9776", "-106.3405", "-106.3171")
     agency <- c("BLM", "USFS", "BLM")
     Total2016 <- ("353", "1112", "9875")
     Total2017 <- c("0", "138", "7435")
     Total2018 <- c("201", "145", "16448")
     Total2019 <- c("153", "0", "9655")
     alluse <- data.frame(site, lat, long, Total2016, Total2017, Total2018, Total2019)
```

Here is my UI code

```
     ui <- navbarPage(
     "Visitor Usage", id = "nav",
     tabPanel("Trailhead Visitation", div(class = "outer",
     tags$head(includeCSS("www/style.css")),
     leafletOutput("UsageMap", width = "100%", height = "100%"),
      absolutePanel(id = "controls", class = "panel panel-default", fixed = TRUE,
                           draggable = TRUE, top = 70, left = "auto", right = 20, bottom =    
                           "auto", width = 330, height = "auto",

      h2("Trailhead Explorer"),

      selectInput("year", label = h4("Year:"),
                  choices = c("2016" = "Total2016",
                              "2017" = "Total2017",
                              "2018" = "Total2018",
                              "2019" = "Total2019"),
                  selected = "", width = "90%", multiple = TRUE),

      tags$div(id="cite", 'Data provided by USFS and BLM and compiled for Chaffee County 
                           Recreation in Balance')
                                   ))))
```

I adjusted my server code to the following:

```
server <- function(input, output, session){

selectedYear <- reactive({switch(input$year,
                         "2016" = alluse$Total2016,
                         "2017" = alluse$Total2017,
                         "2018" = alluse$Total2018,
                         "2019" = alluse$Total2019)
   })

pal1 <- colorBin(palette = "Reds", domain = NULL, bins = 10, pretty = FALSE)

output$UsageMap <- renderLeaflet({
         leaflet(alluse) %>% 
         addProviderTiles("Esri.WorldTopoMap") %>%
        setView(lng = -106.183908, lat = 38.766663, zoom = 9) %>%
        addCircles(data = alluse, lng = alluse$long, lat = alluse$lat,
         weight = 1, radius = sqrt(selectedYear)*30,
         fillColor = ~pal1(selectedYear()),
         popup = paste0(h3("Trailhead:"), alluse$site), color = "#BDBDC3", fillOpacity = 0.8, 
          weight = 1) %>%
  addLegend("bottomleft", pal = pal1, values = selectedYear(), title =   
  "Trailhead Usage")

   })

    observeEvent(input$year, {
    trail_popup <- paste0(h3("Trailhead:"), selectedYear()$site,
                  h4("Total 2016:"), selectedYear()$Total2016,
                  h4("Total 2017:"), selectedYear()$Total2017,
                  h4("Total 2018:"), selectedYear()$Total2018,
                  h4("Total 2019:"), selectedYear()$Total2019)

    leafletProxy("UsageMap", data = selectedYear()) %>%
    clearGroup(c("year"), fillColor = "orange",
         popup = trail_popup, 
         color = "#BDBDC3",
         fillOpacity = 0.8,
         weight = 5)
     })
     }
```

When I run the app I get the following warning messages:

Warning: Error in addCircles: formal argument "weight" matched by multiple actual arguments
[No stack trace available]
Warning: Error in clearGroup: unused arguments (fillColor = "orange", popup = trail_popup, color = "#BDBDC3", fillOpacity = 0.8, weight = 5)
[No stack trace available]

Thanks for any and all help.

I have been working on this multiple year solution for about three weeks off and on and have hit a pretty hard wall. Any help or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was trying to reproduce your code, but `alluse$trailhead` and `alluse$agency` are missing from the example dataset. That said, I must also point out that even if you achieve to plot all years at the same time (and it is doable), is not useful. As the same point in all years has the same coordinates, the only one visible will be the last year drawed. You can do it, but in those points present in more than one selected year you will not be able to visualize or generate a popup but for the last drawed year.

Comment: Hello. I have changed the code to get rid of alluse$trailhead it is now alluse$site and to add the agency column to allude.

That is a good point about viewing the different years at the same time. That was something that the client that I am working for wanted but now that you have pointed it out it completely makes sense not to worry about that. So now I just want the ability to select different years and I am still really confused about how to clear popups.